# Extract data from pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, text-extraction, pdf2htmlex

Please don't mark as duplicate. I have already been through many Stackoverflow links but they didn't solve my problem.

**What I'm trying to do :** I have to extract data from around 1,50,000 pdf files.

**A sample pdf :** All these pdf are identical in structure and  contains data in a tabular format (No image). A snapshot of pdf looks like this.

[image]

**What I've done :** I have used `pdf2htmlEX` terminal command with `Nodejs` to convert the pdf file to html.

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var request = require('request');
var spawn = child_process.spawn;

var url = 'http://url_to_extract_data_from_pdf?Id=' + id;    //id ranges from 1 to 1,50,000
var pdfFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(id + '.pdf');

request(url).pipe(pdfFileStream);

pdfFileStream.on('finish', function () {
    console.log('Pdf file downloaded');

    var pdfToHtml = spawn('pdf2htmlEX', [id + '.pdf']);

    pdfToHtml.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Pdf file converted to html');

        jsdom.env({
            url: "http://localhost:1000/" + id + ".html",    //hard coded url for server -> current server running on localhost:1000
            scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
            done: function (err, window) {

                if(err)
                    console.log(err);

                else {
                    var $ = window.$;

                    //jquery selectors to extract data
                    console.log($(".x14.y30").text().trim());
                    console.log($(".x15.y31").text().trim());
                    console.log($(".x16.y32").text().trim());
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Converted html file looks like this :** The combination of class name x followed by a character and y followed by a character was unique for a particular div. For eg. there was only one div with `xf` and `y10` class.

[image]

**Where I'm stuck :** Although all the pdf are identical in format and structure, the html file generated is not. So lets say `$(".x14.y30").text()` might be giving me something in pdf - 1, it would be giving something else in pdf - 2. I have also looked for some way in which I can modify the way classes were being assigned while a pdf file was converted to html. But all in vain. Extracted data needs to be then stored in a tab separated format.

Using this approach is not mandatory. Any better suggestion is welcome.

Comment: As the structure of the pdfs is the same, so should be the htmls structure. Thus instead of the class names use the order of the divs, ie I would expect that the first div in each html contains the same field, second div in each html is the same field and so on...

Comment: Furthermore, if *all the pdf are identical in format and structure, the html file generated is not*, the difference most likely is caused by some internal difference between the pdfs. Thus, you had better share pdfs with different output.

Comment: Maybe not order but relative order ... like the first div after a div containing the string "date:"